# Android Camera App Programming - Accessing Unbinned Full Pixel Size (e.g. 50 MP) (opensamsung?)

Tags: android, android-camera2

The Camera2 API* allows to build an app to take images from a Samsung Galaxy s22 phone.

Unfortunately, it is only possible to get 12.5 MP images, despite the 50 MP main camera and max. resolution is selected in the API.

However, the Samsung's camera app can take the full 50 MP. So, it appears to be possible.

Does anyone know how the Samsung's camera app takes/accesses 50 MP pictures and how we can build our own app to do the same?

- https://developer.android.com/training/camera2

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, most devices that have [quad-bayer sensors](https://www.sony-semicon.com/en/technology/mobile/quad-bayer-coding.html) don't expose the full-resolution output through the standard camera APIs.

This is in part because the full-resolution mode has unusual pixel layout, in part because the high resolution images are slower to capture and read out, and in part because using it in high resolution mode uses much more power.

The default camera app can use private interfaces to access full-resolution output; sometimes that's in the form of a hidden camera ID, and sometimes it's via custom camera control fields.

Newer Android releases do have support for the new Bayer layout and support listing different characteristics for the high-resolution mode, but devices are only starting to support it now.

Comment: Hmm, that is a bummer. Is there a way to figure out how Samsung does it with their camera app?